# Shared library links removed when PowerShell was removed

Tags: windows, powershell

I uninstalled PowerShell using the "Turn Windows features on or off" menu and after restarting, the links to the shared libraries like *Documents, Downloads* etc. were gone.
Where were those links and how does one get them back?

Comment: What do you mean by "links to the shared libraries" and where were they gone from?  Are you talking about the individual users Documents and Downloads in File Explorer or something else?

Comment: @lx07 Yes, exactly those. They are usually found when expanding the system drive "folder tree". They were where the arrow is pointing: [https://ibb.co/jFzET0](https://ibb.co/jFzET0) - And when you click _This Computer_, it should also show them in the viewing panel on the right of the explorer window.

Comment: Does [this procedure](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/23504-restore-default-location-personal-folders-windows-10-a.html) help?

Comment: @harrymc No, it didn't. Typing "shell:Pictures" in Win-R only brings up the error that "Windows cannot find 'shell:Pictures'", so I couldn't even try it for that folder if I wanted. As for "shell:Desktop" (which does work), it didn't work as the location hasn't been changed. It was still "C:\Users\user\Desktop".

Comment: Can you add screenshots in regedit of the items in the keys `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders ` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`.

Comment: @harrymc From what I can see there (https://ibb.co/nwzW0q and  https://ibb.co/nAZW0q), there's nothing wrong with the paths. I was roaming around the User folder earlier today and I saw that the only user libraries I can access are Desktop, Documents and Downloads. As I've said before, using "shell:Pictures" returns the error that Windows can't find that location.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer :

The link to Pictures is now called `shell:my pictures`.
I couldn't also get `shell:Pictures` to work.

However, `shell:downloads` works well for me. What error are you getting?

Comment: Even when using `shell:my pictures` I get the error that "C:\Users\user\Pictures" can't be found. It seems `shell:my pictures` just redirects to `shell:pictures`.

Comment: Does the folder `C:\Users\user\Pictures` exist? Have you ever moved it elsewhere?

Comment: None of the library folders exist anymore, except Downloads, Desktop and Documents. **I** didn't move them.

Comment: So your problem is not that the links stopped working, but that the folders have disappeared and need to be restored. Try to find them in the Recycle Bin, or restore them from backup, or just create them (they will be empty).

Comment: No, the links are also gone.

Comment: That's debatable, but if your profile is corrupted, you should most likely either return a disk backup if you have one, or create a new profile and move your stuff to it. Create a new profile first and see if this works in it, before moving your stuff.